# Seeking a reliable source on the frequency of words in the Quran

Tags: quran

For a while now, I've been studying the so-called 'numerical miracle of the Quran'.  I'm not interested in all stuff about 19 etc., only in the number of repetition of certain words in the Quran.

If somebody has a reliable source on this topic, I would be grateful for it. (Other than [Dr. Shabir Ally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabir_Ally) or [Dr. Zakir Naik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zakir_Naik)).

Also, more particularly, I've tried to see this for the word 'night' (layl in Arabic) and I've come across 2 different websites:

- this one http://corpus.quran.com/qurandictionary.jsp?q=lyl claims that the number equals to 84, whereas
- this one http://www.alawfa.com/Go.aspx?keyword=%u0644+%u064a+%u0644 which instead gives 125

So I'm confused.

Comment: Check out http://tanzil.net/trans/ -- there are many translations there, including two Arabic versions. Probably all will differ slightly, but you can at least get an approximate idea. Most apps like Word will let you count the occurrences of a word, usually in the "find" feature.

Comment: You should probably read this answer https://islamqa.info/en/69741, which refutes most of the so called numerical miracles that some writers have claimed. It also gives you a clear explanation of the number of certain words that you have raised. The Quran itself is the biggest miracle of Allah. Allah Knows Best.

Comment: The problem with these numerical miricales is that they mostly only work with a unique reading of the Quran. So while the Quran is universal this "miracle" is only a special case.

Comment: One point which may be a reason for difference is: maybe one is searching for the word layl while the other is searching any related word for example the feminine layla or plural layali etc.

Comment: why you do not believe in corpus quran com 's results even if it gives you every occurences of root?! another site you have linked does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I did my research using " http://www.holyquran.net/search/sindex.php " first I searched for the word ( ليل ) but this common with another words like (  قليل، دليل ، ظليل،  تضليل ) but I count only the words that means night I found 92 if we add the word (  ليال ) which comes 3 times so it is 95

Answer (score -2):

check this book
it gives frequencies
https://thequranicwords.wordpress.com/free-version/

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.